# How to understand the profile output of a Django view function

Tags: python, django, profiling

I'm trying to speed up a view in my django project. Using the script from https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/ProfilingDjango, I produced the following output with the top 3 accounting for 57% of my overall time.

```
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
       11    2.898    0.263    2.898    0.263 /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py:406(readline)
        1    0.340    0.340    0.343    0.343 /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py:537(create_connection)
    37587    0.305    0.000    0.346    0.000 /Users/nai/.virtualenvs/tripconomics/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py:130(islink)
```

I have not done much python/application code optimisation before. How am I supposed to interpret this and go about trying to get the tottime down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data descibes how many times a given function was called and how much time was spent within that function.

- ncalls is the number of times that the function was called
- tottime is the total amount of time spent within that function, excluding subfunctions
- percall is the average amount of time that function took per call, or tottime/ncalls
- cumtime is the total amount of time spent within that function, including subfunctions
- percall is similar to the first percall but now for cumtime

So this tells you that a large amount of time is being spent in `socket.py`.  Specifically, `readline` is called a few times and takes a pretty large amount of time each time.  `create_connection` is called only once but that takes even more time than a call to `readline`.  And within `posixpath.py`, `islink` is called a huge amount of times but takes a very small amount of time during each

Given that `create_connection` is only called once(which makes sense), there's likely not much you can do to change that.

It's possible that you could reduce the number of times that `readline` is called by figuring out when the function is called and changing your code to avoid multiple calls to `readline` when one would suffice, but I don't have enough knowledge of your code to say whether that'd be doable.

It seems very likely that you could reduce your calls to `islink` but it would only make a small difference in speed.

Really the only way that you're going to dramatically improve the speed of your code is by reducing those `readline` calls so I'd focus on figuring out when it gets called and minimizing those calls.

Comment: Thanks very much for your response. How can I go about finding the function like what you said here: `It's possible that you could reduce the number of times that readline is called by figuring out when the function is called and changing your code to avoid multiple calls to readline`

Answer (score 0):

This shows that you have 11 calls to readline that take almost 3 seconds. If you're going to lower this, you need to stop doing (or do less of) whatever I/O you're doing (I'm assuming, opening a file and parsing the lines).